# Why are redheads called "gingers" when ginger is yellow?

Tags: etymology

The term "ginger" is often used as a slang term for someone with bright red hair.  But ginger (the spice) is [actually a bright yellow in color.](http://coolcumbers.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/grated-ginger.jpg)  Where does this term come from, then?

Comment: BTW it would appear "nobody has a clue" why red-headed people are called gingers. It's a mystery.